# Updated Password is not showing in firebase database in react native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm working on Forgot password through Firebase. I have done the sign in and login through Firebase. I have successfully changed the Password also. But the updated password is not showing in firebase database.

I have tried this code it's working but the updated password is not showing.

```
      firebase.database().ref('sevenup-a1db1/'+ 
      firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).update({

       password : this.state.password,

           });

     firebase.auth().sendPasswordResetEmail(this.state.email).then(()=>{
     firebase.auth().currentUser.updateProfile({
     displaypassword : password,

      })
     .then ((response) => {
                            // 
    Alert.alert(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)    
    Alert.alert("Success")

     firebase.database().ref('sevenup-a1db1/'+ 
     firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).update({

     password : this.state.password,

     });
     Alert.alert(this.state.password)
       },
```

I want to show the updated password in the firebase database. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please do not save plain text password in your database. You are losing all the benefits of using Firebase Auth which hashes and salts user passwords and provides mechanism to download these users and their hashes via admin sdk /CLI.

Comment: Firebase Auth will handle password resets for you via the sendPasswordResetEmail API - you shouldn't be saving passwords in a database.

Comment: But i want to display the password on my firebase database the email is showing but the updated password is not showing do you have any solution for that